# StreamWriter не записывает данные в файл

Tags: c#, asp.net-webforms

Есть следующий код:

```
catch (FbException e)
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(
           Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.BinDirectory,"log.txt"), FileMode.Create)))
    {
         writer.WriteLine(e.Message);
         writer.Flush();
    }
}
```

Почему-то это код только создает файл, но ничего не записывает туда. Бывали случаи, когда код отрабатывал нормально.

Comment: А вы уверены, что код отрабатывает без ошибок? Попробуйте вывести что-то в консоль (или через `Debug.WriteLine`) перед и после `using`.

Comment: А ещё, может, e.Message пустой? Попробуйте записать в файл ещё что-то.

Comment: откуда исключение прилетает?

Comment: @VladD Message не пустой и до и после using код отрабатывает

Comment: @qzavyer исключения выкидывает Firebird provider при исполнении скрипта.

Comment: Посмотрите свойство CanWrite, возможно вы пишете в файл запрещенный для редактирования.

Comment: @Mirdin файл я создаю сам

Comment: Файл вы можете создавать сами, но у пользователя под которым работает программа, могут разные права на создание и модификацию файла в конкретной директории. Проще говоря проверьте CanWrite.

Comment: @IsM: Если код после using отрабатывает, то **файл записан**. Проверьте, тот ли каталог, где вы его ищете. Проверьте, не переписывает ли файл кто-то ещё позже.

Comment: @VladD Хах, действительно. Я пробовал перенаправить вывод консольного приложения gfix, но он только писал пустой файл. Я думал, что убрал этот код. Спасибо. Можно было бы еще спросить про перенаправление вывода, но думаю для этого лучше создать новый вопрос.

Comment: @IsM: Вот и хорошо, этот вопрос прояснили.

Comment: @VladD а на стеке можно преобразовать комментарий в ответ?

Comment: @IsM: Нет. Но среди комментариев по сути нет ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Может вам надо использовать [`File.AppendText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.file.appendtext(v=vs.110).aspx)? Не забудьте обернуть вызов в [`lock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/c5kehkcz.aspx), если код многопоточный.

```
public sealed class MyClass {
    private static readonly object _writeSync = new object();

    public void LogToFile (Exception ex) {
        let logName = GetLogName();

        lock (_writeSync) {
            File.AppendText(logName, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Так же рекомендовал бы не изобретать велосипед и воспользоваться стандартным решением для логирования - [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/), к примеру.